# SMACK 4.1 Account manager: Private Access Error in account registration

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am getting a strange error while working with account manager in Smack 4.1 for android.

Below is the code snippet:

```
        am = new AccountManager(connection);
    Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // adding or set elements in Map by put method key and value
    // pair
    mp.put("username", "user3");
    mp.put("password", "ps3");
    mp.put("name", "user3");
    mp.put("email", "user3@user.com");
    try {
        am.createAccount("user3", "user3", mp);
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code I've used to connect to Openfire Server is:

```
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        configBuilder.setServiceName("host_name");
        configBuilder.setHost("host_name");
        configBuilder.setPort(5222);
        configBuilder.setCompressionEnabled(false).build();

    AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());

    try {
        System.out.println("connecting");
        connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
        connection.connect();
        System.out.println("connected");
        SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");


    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and is running perfect.

**The exact error is: "*Error:(66, 18) error: AccountManager(XMPPConnection) has private access in AccountManager*"**

I've wasted like 2-3 hours trying to find it but got no answers. I'm a noob so please forgive me if this is a basic question. Also please reply on that as I am stuck and can not move forward.

Thanks alot for the time!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an [instance](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.0.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html) from the accountManager that's relevant to your Xmpp connection.

```
AccountManager ac = AccountManager.getInstance(XMPPConnection connection)
```